# Execute code in objective-c when enter key is pressed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, button, xcode6

I'm working on an Objective-C Xcode project in Xcode 6. I have a textfield and a button that checks what's in the textfield when pressed.

However, I would like the code to run when enter key is pressed instead of the submit button.

I have seen that you can set the key equivalent for a button in Xcode however this option doesn't appear to feature in Xcode 6.

Comment: Become the delegate of the UITextField and then you'll get -[textFieldShouldReturn:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement textField delegate method.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
     [self callYourCodeWantToExecute];
     //return YES; // want to hide keyboard
     //return NO; // want keyboard
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Set delegate for textField
2. In your delegate object handle `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` i.e. do what you need to do when return pressed and return `YES` if you want to text field get return `NO` if you don't want to handle return for text field.

Answer (score 1):

First make your file delegate for UITextField and then add this method to your code ..

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [textField resignFirstResponder];

   return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps.

1. Set delegate of UITExtfield
2. Add tag value if there are multiple textfield
3. Now call the delegate method of UITextfield same as below.

Swift

```
optional func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
```

Hope this helps!